# How to return SQLAlchemy async session?

Tags: python-3.x, database, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, generator

I have this database class in Python with async session maker.

```
class Database(AbstractDatabase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._engine = AsyncEngine(create_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True, future=True))
        self._session_maker = sessionmaker(self._engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
  
    def get_session_maker(self) -> sessionmaker:
        return self._session_maker
```

And I have some repository which retrives data from this database.

```
class UsersRepository(AbstractUsersRepository):
    def __init__(self, db: AbstractDatabase):
        self._db = db

    async def get(self, entity_id: UUID) -> User:
        async with self._db.get_session_maker()() as session:
            return await session.get(User, entity_id)
```

It works well but I don't really like how `get_session_maker` method works and looks. Can I make something like this?

```
class Database(AbstractDatabase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._engine = AsyncEngine(create_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True, future=True))
        self._session_maker = sessionmaker(self._engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

    async def get_session(self) -> AsyncSession:
        async with self._session_maker() as session:
            yield session


class UsersRepository(AbstractUsersRepository):
    def __init__(self, db: AbstractDatabase):
        self._db = db

    async def get(self, entity_id: UUID) -> User:
        session = await self._db.get_session()
        return await session.get(User, entity_id)
```

Well I can't do exactly this variant beacuse I get error `TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression`. And I don't understand exactly why. Doesn't it work like this: `get called` -> `get_session starts session and returns it` -> `get finished exetution` -> `returned to get_session and closed session`?

But maybe there can be some more simple good solutions?